# Kofax Custom Batch Renaming with Unique ID

Tags: c#, .net, ocr, capture, kofax

We have created a custom Utility in .Net C# that creates batches with a Custom Batch Name as predefined.

We want to rename this batch or add a Unique Batch ID i.e. External Batch ID to this Custom Batch.
We are unable to do so as External Batch ID which gets created for the batch automatically is Read Only .

How can we add a Unique Batch ID to this Custom Batch or how can we edit this Batch to rename it with a Custom Batch.

Note: This Custom Batch Name is User Name for Eg: Chris.Gayle

Please help us with the above.

Regards,
Manish Sharma

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to change the batch name once it has been created in Kofax Capture. You should set the correct name when creating the batch instead. You can always set a batch level field or a custom storage string if you need additional meta data for your batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the name of a batch once created.  If using KTM, you can use the Document Routing feature to route all of the documents to a new batch with a different name.  But to be clear: doing that means that KTM Server creates a new batch, which will change the batch ID.

The Batch Naming tab in the Batch Class properties allows you to use {Batch ID} to have the ID automatically be in the name.  You could try simply adding that string when creating your batch name, but I do not know if that will work.  Usually people just set the Batch Naming options, then create a batch without specifying a name, which allows Capture to create a name based on those options.